# Script to insert specific records based on specific criteria in a table automatically when ever a new record has been added with specific criteria

Tags: sql

I have a DB with a table that I want to insert records every time an end user has added a record to that same table for specific criteria automatically.

For example:  Table [Instruments] with fields of

```
Table [Instruments] (
   instrument_calibration_ID (PK, INT, not null, identity increment of 1)
   , instrument ID (FK, INT, not null)
   , Instument_calibration_Type_ID (FK, INT, Not null)
   , Instrument_Status (Varchar(50), not null)
   , user_ID (INT, null), date of calibration (datetime, null)
   , calibration expiration (datetime, null)
```

Here is my script thus far but not achieving the automatically part when end user adds a record:  Help please!

```
INSERT INTO INSTRUMENTS (Instrument_Calibration_ID, Instrument_ID, Instrument_Calibration_Type_ID, Instrument_Status, User_ID, Date_Of_Calibration, Calibration_Expiration)

SELECT Instrument_Calibration_ID + 1, Instrument_ID = '54', Instrument_Calibration_Type_ID, Instrument_Status, User_ID, Date_Of_Calibration, Calibration_Expiration
FROM INSTRUMENTS
WHERE (Instrument_ID='141' AND Instrument_Status='In Calibration');

INSERT INTO INSTRUMENTS (Instrument_Calibration_ID, Instrument_ID, Instrument_Calibration_Type_ID, Instrument_Status, User_ID, Date_Of_Calibration, Calibration_Expiration)

SELECT Instrument_Calibration_ID + 1, Instrument_ID = '58', Instrument_Calibration_Type_ID, Instrument_Status, User_ID, Date_Of_Calibration, Calibration_Expiration
FROM INSTRUMENTS
WHERE (Instrument_ID='54' AND Instrument_Status='In Calibration');

INSERT INTO INSTRUMENTS (Instrument_Calibration_ID, Instrument_ID, Instrument_Calibration_Type_ID, Instrument_Status, User_ID, Date_Of_Calibration, Calibration_Expiration)

SELECT Instrument_Calibration_ID + 1, Instrument_ID = '77', Instrument_Calibration_Type_ID, Instrument_Status, User_ID, Date_Of_Calibration, Calibration_Expiration
FROM INSTRUMENTS
WHERE (Instrument_ID='58' AND Instrument_Status='In Calibration');

INSERT INTO INSTRUMENTS (Instrument_Calibration_ID, Instrument_ID, Instrument_Calibration_Type_ID, Instrument_Status, User_ID, Date_Of_Calibration, Calibration_Expiration)

SELECT Instrument_Calibration_ID + 1, Instrument_ID = '78', Instrument_Calibration_Type_ID, Instrument_Status, User_ID, Date_Of_Calibration, Calibration_Expiration
FROM INSTRUMENT
WHERE (Instrument_ID='77' AND Instrument_Status='In Calibration');SQL
```

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? The 2 are completely different products.#

Comment: If you want to insert a row every time a row is inserted into a table, you probably need to use a trigger. The syntax depends on which DBMS you're using.

Comment: I believe I do but how and only if the row inserted has instrument ID as 141 and the status is in calibration

Comment: @CindyScott which database are you using?

Comment: Its my maintenance DB in SQL

Comment: As my DBMS I'm using SQL Server

Comment: @NichholasHunter I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. Can you help?  I believe I do need a trigger but not sure how to implement that.

Comment: @Larnu I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. Can you help? I believe I need a trigger but not sure how to implement that.

Comment: You *could* use a `TRIGGER` yes. Personally, however, I would handle it in the procedure that is performing your `UPDATE`/`INSERT` statements for the user front end.

Comment: @Larnu care to give an example?  Please

Comment: You have several examples of an `INSERT` in your question, @CindyScott .